# Checking if a double value is an integer - Swift

Tags: swift, int, double

I need to check if a double-defined variable is convertible to Int without losing its value. This doesn't work because they are of different types:

```
if self.value == Int(self.value)
```

where `self.value` is a double.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try 'flooring' the double value then checking if it is unchanged:

```
let dbl = 2.0
let isInteger = floor(dbl) == dbl // true
```

Fails if it is not an integer

```
let dbl = 2.4
let isInteger = floor(dbl) == dbl // false
```

Comment: This does not complete solve the question *"... if a double-defined variable is convertible to Int without losing its value."*. For example, it gives true for 3.1e100, but this value is not convertible to `Int` because it is too large.

Comment: This is genius.

Answer (score 60):

check if `% 1` is zero:

**Swift 3:**

```
let dbl = 2.0
let isInteger = dbl.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let dbl = 2.0
let isInteger = dbl % 1 == 0
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some more informations, what the `% 1` does. I think that will help more people to understand the code.

Comment: he's using what's known as a modulo operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: This will not work correctly. If you truncate 2.2 it is also true, but it's actually false because the value is 0.2.

Answer (score 25):

Swift 3

```
if dbl.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 {
  //it's an integer
}
```

Answer (score 21):

There is now an `Int(exactly:)` initializer that will tell you this directly without the problem of out-of-range whole numbers.

```
if Int(exactly: self) != nil { ... }
```

This will only return a non-nil value if the result can actually be stored in Int exactly. There are many Double values that are "integers" but will not fit in an Int. (See MartinR's comment on the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 7):

**Simple Solution**

I suggest converting the value to `Int` then to `Double` and checking the new value

```
if value == Double(Int(value)) {
// The value doesn't have decimal part. ex: 6.0

} else {
//  The value has decimal part. ex: 6.3

}
```

Answer (score 6):

A small extension to check for this:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var isInt: Bool {
        return floor(self) == self
    }
}
```

Then just do

```
let anInt = 1.isInt
let nonInt = 3.142.isInt
```

Answer (score 6):

The Swifty way:

```
let cals = [2.5, 2.0]

let r = cals.map{ Int(exactly: $0) == nil ?  "\($0)" : "\(Int($0))" }

r // ["2.5", "2"]
```

Hide away in an extension:

```
extension Array where Element == Double {
    var orExactly: [String] {
        map{ Int(exactly: $0) == nil ?  "\($0)" : "\(Int($0))" }
    }
}

cals.orExactly
```

Answer (score 4):

BECAREFUL.

truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:) can be tricky. See below:

Swift 4:

```
//case 1
let reminder = (4.1 * 100).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0)

//case 2
let reminder2 = (410).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0)

// reminder = 0.9999999999999432
// reminder2 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var isWholeNumber: Bool { isNormal ? self == rounded() : isZero }
}

let double = 3.0    
double.isWholeNumber        // true
print(3.15.isWholeNumber)   // false
```

Comment: Just note that this will crash at runtime if the double is too large to be converted to an Int, try `println(3.1e+100.isInteger)`.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer

Answer (score 2):

Using mod (%) won't work anymore.

You can now use:

```
let dbl = 2.0
let isInteger = dbl.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0) == 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

How about converting the Double to an Int (which will cut off decimals), then back to a Double, then comparing this to the original Double?  For example:

```
var dbl:Double = 22/3
dbl == Double(Int(dbl))
// false: dbl = 7.33333... Double(Int(dbl)) = 7.0

dbl = 25
dbl == Double(Int(dbl))
// true: dbl = 25.0, Double(Int(dbl)) = 25.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @ColinE answer, I build an extension that handles when the Double cannot be converted to Int and another function that returns the Int:

```
extension Double {

    func isInt() -> Bool {
        guard Double(Int.min) <= self && self <= Double(Int.max) else {
            return false
        }

        return floor(self) == self
    }

    func toInt() -> Int? {
        guard Double(Int.min) <= self && self <= Double(Int.max) else {
            return nil
        }

        return Int(self)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone,

Xavi