# Swift 3 - Find if the Number is a perfect Square

Tags: swift, perfect-square

I want to know if there is a way of finding if a number is a perfect square in Swift. I have the user enter a number to check if it is a perfect square. Is there a statement or a function? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var number = 9.0

let root = sqrt(number)
let isInteger = floor(root) == root
print("\(root) is \(isInteger ? "perfect" : "not perfect")")
```

That "`isInteger`" bit I found [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447732/checking-if-a-double-value-is-an-integer-swift).

Answer (score 3):

edit/update: **Swift 5.2**

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isPerfectSquare: Bool {
        guard self >= .zero else { return false }
        var sum: Self = .zero
        var count: Self = .zero
        var squareRoot: Self = .zero
        while sum < self {
            count += 2
            sum += count
            squareRoot += 1
        }
        return squareRoot * squareRoot == self
    }
}
```

---

**Playground**

```
4.isPerfectSquare     // true
7.isPerfectSquare     // false
9.isPerfectSquare     // true
(-9).isPerfectSquare  // false
```

Comment: for any consideration, do you think that it should throws an error -nan for example-? or returning `false` would be enough?

Comment: It is a Boolean true or false you can add a precondition but returning false I think it is enough