# Testing if a Decimal is a whole number in Swift

Tags: swift, decimal

Using Swift 3.

I am finding a lot of strange solutions online for checking if a [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/decimal) object is a whole number. Everything feels far more complicated then it needs to be.

Here is my solution:

```
extension Decimal {
    var isWholeNumber: Bool {
        return self.exponent == 1
    }
}
```

In my tests this works. My question is am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You actually want `return self.exponent >= 0` but other than that, I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery true, as opposed to type variable, its instance variable

Comment: Thanks @JohnMontgomery more testing shows I needed to add a few more checks. 
Here is my solution: `return self.isZero || (self.isNormal && self.exponent >= 0)`

Comment: @mgChristopher note that when creating an instance computed property with a getter but without a setter you can omit the `get` keyword and its brackets `var isWholeNumber: Bool { return isZero || (isNormal && exponent >= 0) }`

Comment: Which *"strange solutions"* did you find online? – Just to avoid that someone posts an alternative solution only to get the response *"that's what I found already"* :)

Comment: @MartinR I bet one of these "strange solutions" would be: *convert* to a string and look for the *decimal point* :-)

Comment: I did see that @PauloMattos :D.

Here are some SO post I found [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12298755/1535822), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25552648/1535822), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28447732/1535822). I was tempted to do one of the solution mention in #3, but still felt like more work then needed.

Comment: @mgChristopher: [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12305042/1187415) can be translated to Swift without problems. It is more code, but has the advantage that it uses only *documented* functions – as far as I can see the exact representation of Decimal is nowhere guaranteed, and the [Objective-C variant](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimal?language=objc)  even states that "The fields of NSDecimal are private."

Comment: @MartinR If you are working in ObjC, then yes you should use NSDecimalNumber. I would only use NSDecimal struct in ObjC if I needed extra performance. In Swift [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) is bridged to Decimal. I would also say that Decimal is documented; NSDecimal is not. Also when in doubt we can view the source [code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSDecimal.swift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! Here is what I am using now.

```
extension Decimal {
    var isWholeNumber: Bool { 
        return self.isZero || (self.isNormal && self.exponent >= 0) 
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives a false negative for integer-valued, non-normalized `Decimal`s

Comment: I think for most cases this works, but for like `Decimal(1.00000000000000009).isWholeNumber` returns `true`, 17 digits this, so the key should be don't convert from double to Decimal.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a translation of the Objective-C solution in [Check if NSDecimalNumber is whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298755/check-if-nsdecimalnumber-is-whole-number/12305042#12305042) to Swift:

```
extension Decimal {
    var isWholeNumber: Bool {
        if isZero { return true }
        if !isNormal { return false }
        var myself = self
        var rounded = Decimal()
        NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &myself, 0, .plain)
        return self == rounded
    }
}

print(Decimal(string: "1234.0")!.isWholeNumber) // true
print(Decimal(string: "1234.5")!.isWholeNumber) // false
```

This works even if the mantissa is not minimal (or the exponent not maximal), such as 100 * 10<sup>-1</sup>. Example:

```
let z = Decimal(_exponent: -1, _length: 1, _isNegative: 0, _isCompact: 1, _reserved: 0,
                _mantissa: (100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

print(z) // 10.0
print(z.exponent) // -1
print(z.isWholeNumber) // true
```

Comment: IMHO guard statements have a more natural syntax here: `guard !isZero`, `guard isNormal`

Comment: @Alexander:  No, I do not find the "double negation" in `guard !isZero else { return true }` more natural. Zero has to be treated separately, but it is not an "exceptional case".

Comment: @MartinR: FWIW guard is not for “exceptional cases.” It’s for cases that should force exiting the current scope. Anyway usage of if vs. guard is usually up to the discretion of the implementer (I’d have used guard here but YMMV). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Frizlab: Sure, guard was introduced to solve the "if let pyramid of doom", but can be used with any boolean expression. – Perhaps I expressed myself badly, I am just opposed to using `guard` for each and every "early return" situation. In this case, `if isZero { return true }` is easier to understand than `guard !isZero else { return true }` *in my opinion.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Swift but I'm comparing the input to a rounded input:

```
let input = 2.9

round(input) == input
        3        2.9
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure can works in all cases but that maybe a more coincise option

```
extension Decimal {

    static var decimalSeparator: String { return NumberFormatter().decimalSeparator }

    var isFraction: Bool {
        return self.description.contains(Decimal.decimalSeparator)
    }

    var isWhole: Bool {
        return !isFraction
    }

}
```

Comment: Converting number to string, and then looking for a symbol in the string is one of the slowest and resource consuming ways to solve the problem possible.